# What's the default values of second parameter (`timePeriod`) of `trader_rsi()` PHP function?

Tags: php, function

What's the default values of second parameter (`timePeriod`) of [trader_rsi()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trader-rsi.php) PHP function?

*In the site, just talked about valid range of values:*

> timePeriod:
>   Number of period. Valid range from 2 to 100000.

Answer (score 0):

The `timePeriod` parameter is not optional, so there are no default value.

Comment: 1) I thinks that you means is it optional or it's not require! 2) and so I know about optional, but anyway in RSI calculation will used of a specific time period value.

Comment: The documentation indicates that it's optional.